# jquery enable/disable is not working in mobile device

Tags: jquery, mobile, jquery-plugins

using jQuery version 2.1.1,i am disabling the the drop-down control on page load , on first drop-down change i need to enable second drop-down. disabling is  working fine on page load.. but i cant enable it back on change event in jQuery.. i tried the following

```
        $("#mRFFacility").change(function () { 
         $("#mRFWorkspace").prop('disabled', false);
         $('#mRFWorkspace').removeAttr('disabled');
        });
         kindly help me to resolve this issue
```

Comment: is change event getting triggered? try giving alert inside the change event.

Comment: Can you give jsFiddle with your code?

Comment: alert is working in change event.

Comment: This code is correct, check the id of drop-downs or check in console are your getting any errors in it.

Comment: id of dropdown are correct and i dont get any errors in console

Answer (score 1):

Here is some working code with the desired behaviour. Compare it to what you have and see why it isn't working for you. The part of your code that you have provided looks fine, but you only need remove the disabled attribute as shown below.

```js
$("#mRFWorkspace").prop('disabled', 'disabled');

$("#mRFFacility").change(function () {
  $('#mRFWorkspace').removeAttr('disabled');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="mRFFacility">
  <option value="0">Facility A</option>
  <option value="1">Facility B</option>
</select>
<br/>
<select id="mRFWorkspace">
  <option value="0">Workspace A</option>
  <option value="1">Workspace B</option>
</select>
```

Comment: it works fine here.. but its is not working in my code

Comment: Add a jsFiddle of your full code and I'll be able to see what is going on.

Comment: the dropdown values are from backend.. dynamically added.... will  add js fiddle code here

Comment: can you get the jsfiddle to fail on your mobile device? without any test data, you onChange will not be triggered and you haven't added your onChange event.

Comment: i have added on change event

Comment: Great, specify you version of jQuery in the javascript library drop down to left in jsFiddle. Once you do this it will work as expected. Are you saying this behaviour doesn't work only on your mobile device? What is the mobile device that you are using? Are you deploying this html to a server?

Comment: I've just tested this on an iPhone 4S and it's working as expected. I've updated the jQuery setting for you at jsfiddle.net/mb1uLauk/2. Go to this link from your iPhone and try it out.